# How to add more than one select element with same set of ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angular-ngmodel

This question may be very trivial but its driving me nuts. 
I can have n number of  elements on my page that are added dynamically. All these will have the same set of options for them.

```
<select class="form-control action"
      data-ng-options="action.name for action in statementData" 
      data-ng-model="selectedRules.statementOptions"
>
```

This is the mark-up for one of such elements.

Problem: When I change or select something in one select element, all the others are updated. I dont want that. This might be happening coz of the same model object. But if i remove model then there is no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply copy the variable, its passed by reference and change to one will change the other.

Try creating two variables using angular.copy() and use it for two select options.

Try something like below :

```
<!-- First select -->
<select class="form-control action"
  data-ng-options="action.name for action in statementData" 
  data-ng-model="selectedRules.statementOptions">

<!-- Second select -->
<select class="form-control action"
  data-ng-options="action.name for action in statementData1" 
  data-ng-model="selectedRules.statementOptions">
```

In Controller you will have to do.

```
$scope.statementData1 = angular.copy(statementData);
```

By using angular.copy() separate copies are made for both variables in $scope.

Comment: even I thought about using angular.copy. But the problem here is that, I can have hundreds of such select elements, which are added dynamically and I don't know how many of them will appear on the page. User can click on a button to add these elements, any number of times required.

Comment: maybe if I have a way to pass a new model in the select statement itself. That might work. But I am unable to figure out how.

Comment: One logic I can think as of now - Create an array in scope. Push inital statementData variable in it. Then when user clicks button to create new select...make a new copy in runtime like statementData1 and push it in array. So all user select values will be in array and you can use it as per business requirements

Comment: Actually I think we need to have an array for copies of model and not the data. I used this approach, made an array of models and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Copy that original model to other component. Use angular.copy() for example.

Comment: even I thought about using angular.copy. But the problem here is that, I can have hundreds of such select elements, which are added dynamically and I don't know how many of them will appear on the page. User can click on a button to add these elements, any number of times required.